Compression and hyperreflexivity
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a von Neumann algebra acting on the separable Hilbert space $H.$ Is there some projection $S$ belonging to the center $Z(\mathcal{A})$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that the algebra $S \mathcal{A} S$ is hyperreflexive?
Recall that a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{M}$ acting on the Hilbert space $K$ is hyperreflexive if there exists a constant $0<k<\infty$ such that $d(T, \mathcal{M})\leq k \cdot r_{\mathcal{M}}(T)\,\forall T\in\mathcal{B}(K),$ where $$r_{\mathcal{M}}(T)=\sup_{P\in\rm{Lat}(\mathcal{M})}||P^{\perp} T P||.$$
Also recall that if $S$ is a projection in $\mathcal{M}$ then $S \mathcal{M} S$ is a von Neumann algebra acting on $S(K)$.

My idea is the following one: Since $Z(\mathcal{A})$ is abelian, its commutant $(Z(\mathcal{A}))^\prime$ has a cyclic vector, let $\xi\in H\setminus \left{0\right}.$ Let $P$ be the projection onto $\overline{\mathcal{A}^\prime \xi}.$ Then $P\in\mathcal{A}$ and we can define $S$ to be the central support of $P.$ But I cannot prove that $S \mathcal{A} S$ is hyperreflexive. Maybe there is something missing.

I’ve never seen hyperreflexivity before, so maybe I’m misunderstanding something, but it seems to me you can easily obtain a counterexample by choosing $\mathcal{A}$ to be a factor acting on $H$ in such a way so that its commutant is nontrivial (for example, this is true for the standard form representation of any nontrivial factor). Then $S$ must be $1$, but for any $T \in \mathcal{A}’ \setminus \mathbb{C}$, we have $d(T, \mathcal{A}) > 0$ and $r_\mathcal{A}(T) = 0$.

@DavidGao your example shows that the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is not hyperreflexive but this is exactly the open problem of hyperreflexivity of all von Neumann algebras introduced by Arveson.

I suppose I must be misunderstanding something then. What does $\mathrm{Lat}(\mathcal{M})$ mean, in that case? I was assuming it means the projection lattice of $\mathcal{M}$, but maybe that’s not what it is?

$\rm{Lat}(\mathcal{M})=\left{P\in\rm{pr}(\mathcal{B}(H))\mid P^{\perp} X P=0,\forall X\in \mathcal{M}\right}$

Oh, I guess I was misunderstanding then. In that case $\mathrm{Lat}(\mathcal{M}) = \mathrm{pr}(\mathcal{M}’)$ and what I said before doesn’t make much sense. But the example still means that your question isn’t much weaker than just asking whether all vNa are hyperreflexive. (In particular, your question having a positive answer would most definitely imply all factors are hyperreflexive. I wouldn’t be surprised if it actually implies all vNa are hyperreflexive.) Given that you said that is open, I highly doubt you can get an answer here.

Here is the situation: All type I and type III factors are hyperreflexive. All type $II_1$ factors with $II_1$ commutant are also hyperreflexive. Finally, all $II_{\infty}$ factors with $II_{\infty}$ commutant are also hyperreflexive. So, the big problem is the case of a $II_{\infty}$ factor with commutant of type $II_1.$

Thanks for the information. That doesn’t really solve anything though. Just choose a II$1$ factor with a II$\infty$ commutant or equivalently a II$_\infty$ factor with a II$_1$ commutant, and your question reduces to an open problem. I wouldn’t bet on getting a solution idea for an open problem here. MSE isn’t that advanced. If you truly want to try, I’d suggest moving the problem to MathOverflow with all these additional information, where there are more actual researchers in vNa.
